# How to transfer the elements from one JList to other JList in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlist

I have two JList on a swing GUI. Now I want that when a user clicks on a button (say TransferButton) the selected elements from one JList is added from the first JList to the second JList and remove those selected elements from the first JList.

Comment: I assume you looked at the javadoc and tried one or two things before asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model doesn't know about selection.

The JList provides several methods to get the selected item or selected index.  Use those methods to get the items and add them to the other list's model.

Answer (score 2):

You have two `JList`s, then you also have their respective `ListModel`s. Depending on how you implemented them you can just remove the elements from one model and add them to the other. Note, though, that the `ListModel` interface doesn't care for more than element access by default, so you probably have to implement `add` and `remove` methods there by yourself.

Comment: At present, the list models of both the JList is DefaultListModel but I can change that if required. The DefaultListModel doesn't provide any method like getSelectedItem or getSelectedItems ...

Comment: Right, you have to implement your own model in that case. Or derive from DefaultListModel and extend it appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

```
DefaultListModel leftModel = new DefaultListModel();
leftModel.addElement("Element 1");
leftModel.addElement("Element 2");
leftModel.addElement("Element 3");
leftModel.addElement("Element 5");
leftModel.addElement("Element 6");
leftModel.addElement("Element 7");

JList leftList = new JList(leftModel);

DefaultListModel rightModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList rightList = new JList(rightModel);
```

Let's imagine you have two JList components as described in the code above (left and right). You must write following code to transfer selected values from the left to the right JList.

```
for(Object selectedValue:leftList.getSelectedValuesList()){
    rightModel.addElement(selectedValue);
    leftModel.removeElement(selectedValue);
}
```